# Create two dataframe from a given dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Assume that I have the following dataframe

```
id  item_name      item_date   item_quantity
0   computer hp    01/10/2018   50
1   computer hp    02/10/2018  201
2   computer dell  01/10/2018  45
3   computer dell  02/10/2018  59
```

I would like a way to create two dataframe from this one :

## new_df1

```
id  item_name      item_date   item_quantity
0   computer hp    01/10/2018   50
1   computer hp    02/10/2018  201
```

## new_df2

```
id  item_name      item_date   item_quantity
2   computer dell  01/10/2018  45
3   computer dell  02/10/2018  59
```

Can you explain me how to do this with a minimum (?) time ?
Thank you. If you don't understand, just let me know. I will rephrase it ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can groupby and use `transform(min)` to find the min date in each group then use `np.split()` to split on the index and create new dataframes on each groups min date

```
# group df on name and the find the min date of each group
group = df.groupby('item_name')['item_date'].transform('min')

# filter find the matches of min date in the original df
x = df.loc[df['item_date'] == group]

# get the indices
idx = list(x.index.values)

# split the df into dfs
dfs = np.split(df, idx)
```

dfs[1]

```
    id  item_name   item_date   item_quantity
0   0   computer hp 1/10/2018   50
1   1   computer hp 2/10/2018   201
```

dfs[2]

```
    id  item_name   item_date   item_quantity
2   2   computer dell   1/10/2018   45
3   3   computer dell   2/10/2018   59
```

Answer (score 1):

IF you just want to split the dataframe on a given index, use the following:

```
import pandas as pd 



df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'B': [1, 2, 3, 2], 'C': ['A','B','C','D']})

n = 2

df1 = df[:n]
df2 = df[n:]




   Date  B  C
0     1  1  A
1     2  2  B
   Date  B  C
2     3  3  C
3     4  2  D
```